# Get sum total for each column in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking forward to get the sum total of each column using d3.js in a dynamic way. Please find the example-

```
key  | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
mike | 1      | 3      | 5      | 7      
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
mila | 2      | 4      | 6      | 8
-----+--------+--------+--------+--------
minda| 9      | 11     | 13     | 15
```

Here, sum total for value1 is 12, value2 is 18. I need the sum for each of the column in a dynamic way.

Comment: what do you mean 'in a dynamic way ?'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're loading your data, but here's one way that you could do it.

```js
var data = [
  { key: "mike",  value1: 1, value2: 3, value3: 5, value4: 7}, 
  { key: "mila",  value1: 2, value2: 4, value3: 6, value4: 8}, 
  { key: "minda", value1: 3, value2: 5, value3: 7, value4: 9}, 
  { key: "mandy", value1: 4, value2: 6, value3: 9, value4: 10}
];

var cols = d3.keys(data[0]),
    table = d3.select("#vis").append("table"),
    totals = {};

data.forEach(function(d) {
    cols.forEach(function(k) {
        if (k !== "key") {
            if (k in totals) {
                totals[k] += d[k];
            } else {
                totals[k] = d[k];
            }
        }
    });
});

totals['key'] = 'totals';

data.push(totals);

table.append("thead").append("tr").selectAll("th")
     .data(cols)
   .enter().append("th")
     .html(function(d) {
         return d;
      });

var rows = table.append("tbody").selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("tr")
                .html(function(d) {
                    html = "";
                    cols.forEach(function(k) {
                        html += "<td>" + d[k] + "</td>";
                    });

                    return html;
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="vis"></div>
```

It's pretty simple really, get the column names from your `data` (stored in `cols`) and for each row in your `data`, loop over those column names, adding the values in that column together and storing them in a new variable (`totals` in this example).

To display it, I'm just creating a table with the `totals` appended to the `data` so it creates a new row with the totals in it.